# SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, query

I am new to SQL with no training what so ever and what little I do know I taught myself so please be gentle with me.

I have a table that has 4 columns. I will call them `customers`, `customer code`, `date of purchase` and `salesman`.

I need to run a query that gives me all the customers that had the same date of purchase and same customer code by the same salesman.

I have all the columns pulling from the database and putting that data INTO `#pull1` but I can not figure out how to do a query based on those columns matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customers, customer_code, Count(customer_code), date_of_purchase, Count(date_of_purchase), salesman, Count(salesman)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY customers, customer_code, date_of_purchase, salesman
HAVING (Count(customer_code) > 1) AND (Count(date_of_purchase)) > 1 AND (Count(salesman) >1)
```